# Get printer status using C#

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering how can I get the printer status in C#? I'm new to C# and I found the System.Printing.dll and tried to implement it but it didn't work. Is there a better way to do it? or how can I use the System.Printing function as I didn't find any good documentation regarding it.

```
public static void Main(ref String statusReport, PrintQueue pq)
        {

            if ((pq.QueueStatus & PrintQueueStatus.PaperProblem) == PrintQueueStatus.PaperProblem)
            {
                statusReport = statusReport + "Has a paper problem. ";
            }

            Main(ref statusReport, pq);
            return;
        }
```

here is the System.printing docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing?view=netframework-4.8 . basically what im trying to do is get the printer status. out of paper or low on toner ..etc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide some code you tried to do what you are asking? It would also be helpful if you provided any documentation that you are using to accomplish this.

Comment: could you check my edited code now?

Comment: System.Printing namespace only provide APIs for checking queues, online/offline (reachable or not), and print jobs. To check for printer's specific status such as out of paper, out of ink/toner, these statuses are specific to printer's brand and hardware. SO is not the place to ask for this.

Comment: @Eriawan, that is not the case. The `PrintQueue` class seems to provide access to pretty much all of the status information that would normally be displayed when viewing the queue in Windows. If something manufacturer-specific was required, fair enough. But the System.Printing namespace looks like it should provide what @Sam needs.

Comment: @NigelWhatling thanks for the comment. I think you're right about some of the basic status that's provided by `PrintQueue`, especially about out of toner and paper status. Your answer is enough to be a marked answer.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something I've ever worked with, but I took a quick look at the System.Printing namespace. You're probably looking in the right area. If you post the code you have that isn't working, someone may be able to help out.

As a quick example, this little console app will (should) dump the current [status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printqueuestatus) of all local [print queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printqueue):

```
using System;
using System.Printing;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LocalPrintServer localPrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();

        foreach (PrintQueue printQueue in localPrintServer.GetPrintQueues())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{printQueue.FullName}  [{printQueue.QueueStatus}]");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nigel for your reply. The printer is on a server not a local server how can I post its Ip? whats the difference between printQueue.FullName and printQueue.QueueStatus ? could you show me an example using a status and I edited my post with the code.

Comment: Looks like you should be able to connect to a remote printer using the PrintServer class (e.g. `PrintServer ps = new PrintServer("\\192.168.0.42");`). What exactly are you trying to accomplish, though?

Comment: Im trying to get the status of a printer ( on or off, no toner.. etc ) the printer is on the server. Later on I will build an API that shows the printer status, scanner and some other modules.

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with that status. You probably don't want to re-invent the wheel too much. If you look at the `PrintQueue` class, it already has handy properties like `HasPaperProblem`, `IsOffline`, and `IsTonerLow`. Once you have the queue you're after, just use the data to do what you need.

Comment: I tried to use it like this 'static void Main()
        {
            PrintServer ps = new PrintServer(@"\\192.168.0.225");

            foreach (PrintQueue printQueue in ps.GetPrintQueues()) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{printQueue.FullName}  [{printQueue.QueueStatus}]");
                Console.WriteLine($"{printQueue.IsDoorOpened + "Door is open"}  [{printQueue.QueueStatus}]");
            } '  .... but I keep on getting this error ... System.Printing.PrintServerException: 'An exception occurred while creating the PrintServer object. Win32 error: '

Comment: The error was cut off in your comment. Could you add your new code along with the result (error) to your question?

Comment: I managed to make the code work with `LocalPrintServer()` property but `PrintServer()` keeps on sending this error `System.Printing.PrintServerException: 'An exception occurred while creating the PrintServer object. Win32 error: The printer name is invalid.` I used the code u mentioned

Comment: Are you sure that IP address is correct? I can replicate that error if I put in an intentionally incorrect value. Can test with a true remote "server" at the moment, but can connect to local via \\hostname and IP.

Comment: The IP address is correct I can ping it and open the web interface from the browser. but everything works fine if I set it up as a local server.

Comment: Firewall restrictions perhaps? I think you need ports 445 and 139 for file/printer sharing.